# Get multiple selected values from list in arrraylist on select in Spring MVC

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, arraylist

I have a bean class named AnnouncementDetails having attributes

```
Now on submit i want to get the values of the selected users in selectedUsers Arraylist. Any idea how to do that? ..............................................
```

Comment: ArrayList<String> users;
    ArrayList<String> selectedUsers;
    
    Now while displaying the page m setting the values of users and displaying on JSP page 
    
    <form:form name="addAnnouncement" action="insertAnnouncement.htm"
      onsubmit="return ValidaeAddAnnoucementForm()" modelAttribute="AnnouncementDetails">
    
    <select name="select" id="select" multiple="multiple" class="selectList">
    <c:forEach items="${AnnouncementDetails.users}" var="user">
    <form:option value="${user}">${user}</form:option>
    </c:forEach>
    </select>
    </form:form>

Answer (score 0):

Change datatype to String array and then convert to arraylist by Arrays.asList(selectedUsers).

```
   String [] selectedUsers
```